# Command to find if VT-d or IOMMU is supported or not in linux

Tags: linux, passthrough, pci, intel-vt-x

I wanted to find out if my Linux server supports PCI passthrough.
For that, I need to know if my CPU has [VT-d](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-virtualization-technology-for-directed-io-vt-d-enhancing-intel-platforms-for-efficient-virtualization-of-io-devices.html) or [IOMMU](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/blogs/intels-virtualization-for-directed-io-aka-iommu-part-1.html) enabled or not, but I couldn't find the way.

The following is the `lscpu` command output:

```
Blockquote
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             4
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 60
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               3399.996
BogoMIPS:              6799.99
Virtualization:        VT-x
Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon rep_good nopl xtopology eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq vmx ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt arat md_clear spec_ctrl intel_stibp
```

By inspecting the specs for my Intel CPU, I did find out that it supported the VT-d, but I would be glad if anyone could give any command for directly knowing if the CPU supports the same.

My Linux distro is CentOS 7.9

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: lscpu| grep - - color=auto vt\-d should do it?

Comment: the command output is : (standard input):CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
(standard input):On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
(standard input):Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
(standard input):Virtualization:        VT-x
(standard input):NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
grep: color=auto: No such file or directory
grep: vt-d: No such file or directory